# Best fit for including or ignoring vQmod files in versioning

Tags: git, version-control, bazaar, opencart2.x, vqmod

I am using some vQmod extensions in a current project (built with OpenCart) and I wonder if it is actually useful to include all the files of the `<vqmod>` folder into version control.

At this time, I suppose that it could be correct to include:

```
<install>
<xml>
.htaccess
pathReplaces.php
readme.txt
vqmod.php
```

But I wonder about the relevance (particularly in the context of a local development which is later pushed into a remote branch) to include also:

```
<logs>
<vqcache>
checked.cache
modes.cache
```

Thanks for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only files I'd bother using version control with for VQMod are your `.xml` files in `/vqmod/xml`. The VQMod system (I'm an author of it by the way) itself is just a couple of files and changes so infrequently that it's probably not going to be worth versioning the `vqmod.php` file or `pathReplaces.php` especially if you don't rewrite paths.

The files you've noted are all just temp files that will alter constantly as you add/remove VQMod files and have issues with any. None of them have any relevance to the functionality and should therefore be added to your `.gitignore` file

Comment: A direct answer by one of the authors is _perfect_: thanks for this clarification.